# Составить регулярное выражение для последнего числа в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Найти число, являющееся последним в строке. Число от 1. Строка может заканчиваться на число или слэш. В ответе должен быть только 1 элемент.

Исходная строка может быть:

1. "http://domen:8000/one/two/tree/123456789/"
2. "http://domen:8000/one/two/tree/123456789"
3. "http://domen:8000/one/two/tree/1"
4. "http://domen:8000/one/123/two/1234567890123456789/"

Результат

1. 123456789
2. 123456789
3. 1
4. 1234567890123456789

Мои варианты регулярного выражения

1. /(?:/)(\d+)(?:/)?$/
2. (?:/)\d+(?:/)?$

Результат

1. /123456789/, 123456789 - 2 элемента, нужен только один : 123456789
2. /123456789/ - 1 элемент, но входят в ответ слеши, нужно без них

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
/\d+(?=\/?$)/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/BVrsyT/1).

**Подробности**

- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?=\/?$)` - сразу после цифр должен быть необязательный символ `/` и конец строки.